# How do I clear previous variable in cache during the Ajax call while sending variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I am unable to stop the previous variable loading during the ajax call.

Please find onclick I am passing the variable and sending the value to ajax call to PHP script.

I've got the data:

rnc.csv

```
DLRNC01
DLRNC02
DLRNC03
DLRNC04
DLRNC05
DLRNC06
DLRNC07
DLRNC08
DLRNC09
DLRNC10
DLRNC11
DLRNC12
DLRNC13
DLRNC14
```

code

```
<?php

    if (($handle = fopen("rnc.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $i=0;
        $values=array();
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

?>

<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="pop(<?php echo "'".$data[0]."'"; ?>)" > <?php echo $data[0]; ?></a></br>
<?php               
    }
    fclose($handle);
    }
    else{
        echo "File not found";
    }
?>

<div id="container1"></div>

<script>

//even I cleared the chache using the cache:false

//for every click different variable is passing to the ajax call and than to PHP script
        function pop(rnc)
        {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax1.php',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            //dataType:'json',
            data:{rnc:rnc},
            success: function(data){

                        $("#container1").html(data);

                        setInterval(function(){

                                console.log(rnc);

                                $("#container1").html(data);

                        },2000);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

ajax1.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['rnc']; ?>
```

When I am passing the value to the rnc_value.php, after clicking the values of the file two to more , than the ajax call is echoing what ever the values having previous called displaying for every 5 seconds.

When I do console.log in the browser :

```
ajax.php:344 DLRNC01
ajax.php:344 DLRNC05
ajax.php:344 DLRNC07
ajax.php:344 DLRNC04
ajax.php:344 DLRNC01
ajax.php:344 DLRNC02
2 ajax.php:344 DLRNC05
ajax.php:344 DLRNC06
ajax.php:344 DLRNC07
ajax.php:344 DLRNC04
ajax.php:344 DLRNC01
ajax.php:344 DLRNC02
```

Please help me what is the solution..

Comment: You have a setInterval inside your success handler, operating on the data and results of your ajax call every 2 seconds.  This will continue until you terminate that interval.  Is this what you want?  I have to ask, what is your intended purpose of using that interval?  And just to make sure i'm clear.  That success callback interval is operating on EACH ajax call that results in a success.  If you call it three times, you will have three separate intervals running, each displaying the data and results from each different invocation of the ajax call.

Comment: @Taplar..yes..when ever i call the ajax call..it has to invoke individually and set inverval has to set for called variable and its has to refresh only that particular variable for every 2 sec....this is what i want ...pls let me know..

Comment: hi @Taplar....the setInterval after the success handler should operate only on clicked variable and than refresh...but should not refresh the previous variable interval....please help

Comment: I believe what your wanting is to have your setInterval around your ajax call.  This will cause the ajax call to invoke every 2 seconds (since your timeout is 2000) and update your page with the results.  If, however, there is the possibility that you can invoke this ajax call with different parameters later, you'll probably want to store interval (ex. someVariable = setInterval(...) ) and then before you start your second call with the new parameters do someVariable.clearInterval() to stop the previous interval so you don't have two ajax calls competing for updating your page.

Comment: Thanks for the logic...can you pls show help me with code ..

Comment: @Taplar ...I tried with the clearInterval ..Its not working...and the setInterval is stopped after clearInterval is called..

Comment: @Taplar ..dude please help...

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but your setInterval inside ajax success seems pointless. You're assigning data to an element every 2 seconds while data will be the same, unless another ajax call is made. So as Tapler answered below, probably you'll need to have your ajax call inside the setInterval and clear it before making a new ajax call. And please stop spamming other places about your question, or repeating what you've already said.

Comment: @Samurai   yes, I have done..like Taplar said...but the previous values are displaying again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, since our comments are going a little long, I'll move it to an answer box.  So here is currently what you have...

```
function pop(rnc) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax1.php',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data:{rnc:rnc},
        success: function(data){
            $("#container1").html(data);

            setInterval(function() {
                console.log(rnc);
                $("#container1").html(data);
            },2000);
        }
    });
}
```

What I'm suggesting is:

```
//storage for the interval that will persist beyond the function call
var popInterval = null;
function pop(rnc) {
    //if it is not the first invocation of pop, need to kill the previous interval
    if (popInterval !== null) {
        clearInterval(popInterval);
    }

    //start the new interval with the new 'rnc' data provided and store the interval reference
    popInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax1.php',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data:{rnc:rnc},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(rnc);
                $("#container1").html(data);
            }
        });
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: ...its not working ...please check again it is calling the previous variable...kindly check...

Comment: Finally I got the solution....Thanks very much...I am very thankful to u...thanks

Comment: This will run ajax every 2 seconds?