# Get value from paper-checkbox if checked

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184690/javascript-get-the-value-of-checkbox-if-checked-without-button-clicked) has been asked and I am trying to do the same with paper-checkbox in Polymer 1.1

**Here is my full setup:**

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
 <template>
  <firebase-collection
   location="htt://www.abc.com/users"
   order-by-child="formatOrder"
   data="{{users}}">
  </firebase-collection>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]" as="user">
   <paper-checkbox id="user-checked" value="{{user.name}}" on-tap="userRequest">click</paper-checkbox>
  </template>
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "my-app",

   userRequest: function() {
    var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('#user-checked');
    for(var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
     cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      if(this.checked) {
       console.log(this.value);
      }
     });
    }
   },
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

So basically I want when the checkbox is checked, it shows their name. If I decided to add another checkbox for their age, it does the same. But the code above runs the code twice, when checked or unchecked, even three times. How to get it to execute once when checked and not to execute when unchecked?

Comment: Is the function 'userRequest' called twice or just the log printed twice.

Comment: Well...in the console, I see the result being printed twice. If I hit the button again, I goes up by 2x or even 4x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time someone taps the checkbox you add an event listener for the change event in your `userRequest` function. Thus, the more often the user taps the checkbox, the more event listeners you will have for the same event. They will all get called each time the event fires. But actually you only need one and you can add in the markup directly .

```
<paper-checkbox on-change="checkboxChanged">click</paper-checkbox>
```

Then in your event handler you can access the checkbox value via `event.target.value`

```
checkboxChanged : function(event){
    if(event.target.checked) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Maria. Thanks. I was assuming that the function was being called more than once in the function I am calling. All is now great. Thank you!